# converting to math from economics major

Tags: reference-request, finance, fractals, chaos-theory

Recently, i'm majoring in honour track of economics taking econometrics statistics courses and minoring in mathematics taking advanced calculus, real analysis ,linear algebra courses.
Upon research on some journals and internet, i fell in love with fractal geometry . I want to go delve into that region to learn its theory and applications in economics, finance and some other real world phenomena. But, if I take a book by chance on the topic, its level is much likely to be higher than mine. So, i want a suggestion where to start to learn theory of chaos and fractal geometry and its applications to finance. What are some prerequisites to deeply understand the materials that you'll suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Measure theory is the first thing that pops into my mind, since in order to understand the concept of Hausdorff (fractal) dimension, you must understand what the Hausdorff measure and its properties are.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Measure-Integration-Edition/dp/9812566546 ... this book is suggested somewhere else. do you suggest it for self-study? and do i need to take topology course to understand this book?

Comment: I haven't read that book myself, but from the Amazon preview it looks ok. There are lots of old questions here at stackexchange about good measure theory books, so you could have a look at those (just search "measure theory book" or something, you'll see there are plenty of options to go). As for whether this particular book suits you best, I believe only you can tell in the long run. As for prerequisites, a course on real analysis (at the level of "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin, or similar) should be enough, you don't need more than the point-set topology introduced there.